# Windows Threading API: Calculate PI value with multiple threads

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, api

I am currently working on this project where I need to calculate the value of PI...

When specifying only one thread works perfectly and I get **3.1416**[...] but when I specify to solve the process in 2 or more threads I stop getting the **3.1416** value, this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

//const int numThreads = 1;
//long long num_steps = 100000000;

const int numThreads = 2;
long long num_steps = 50000000;

double x, step, pi, sum = 0.0;
int i;

DWORD WINAPI ValueFunc(LPVOID arg){
    for (i=0; i<=num_steps; i++) {
        x = (i + .5)*step;
        sum = sum + 4.0 / (1. + x*x);
    }

    printf("this is %d step\n", i);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int count;
    clock_t start, stop;
    step = 1. / (double)num_steps;
    start = clock();

    HANDLE hThread[numThreads];
    for ( count = 0; count < numThreads; count++) {

            printf("This is thread %d\n", count);
        hThread[count] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ValueFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);

    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(numThreads, hThread, TRUE, INFINITE);

    pi = sum*step;
    stop = clock();
    printf("The value of PI is %15.12f\n", pi);
    printf("The time to calculate PI was %f seconds\n", ((double)(stop - start) / 1000.0));

}
```

I get this wrong output when specifying 2 threads:

[image: Wrong PI value]

Comment: In this particular scenario, there's no need for synchronization objects: simply have each thread add up its own part of the sum separately, then sum the values for each thread at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your program, when using two threads, allows both threads to directly manipulate a global/shared resource 'sum' without any synchronization protection.

In other words, both threads can manipulate 'sum' at the same time.  The value of 'sum' at any point will not be what is expected (ie: as it was with only one thread).

Your program needs to implement some sort of access synchronization between the two threads; such as semaphores, spin-locks, mutex, atomic operations, etc.  If implemented properly, these features would allow the two (or more) threads to share the single task (of calculating PI).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mutexes to access data shared by multiple threads or have the data local to the particular thread and then colate the answer when all the threads have completed.